# Unity Oculus Quest First Person Controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

My Goal:

Have a simple first person controller implemented for Oculus quest where I can move the player around using the dpads on either controllers

Steps I followed:

```
Started a new project

Switched target to android and entered all the data required in Oculus settings and player settings

Downloaded Oculus Integration from the Asset Store

Placed the OVRPlayerController in my scene on a platform with a collider

Build and run
```

Results:

What I noticed was that moving any of the dpads on either controllers moved the player a tiny bit instead of a constant movement. It is as if the dpad input is treated like a button input. When I logged the following lines :

```
     OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.RawAxis2D.Any);
     OVRInput.Get(OVRInput.Axis2D.Any);
```

The output only changes when the dpad is initially moved and then goes back to (0,0) even if the dpad is still being moved

Environment Details:

OS: Windows 10 x64

Unity Version: 2019.1.10.f1

Target Platform: Android

Oculus Integration Version: 1.39

Questions:

Can the OVRPlayerController be fixed to provide constant player movement like the one provided in the Standard Assets package?

Is there a way to get a constant reading of the controllers dpad as an axis just like we do do when we use Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") and Input.GetAxis("Vertical") ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found online and it worked for me. I had the same issue like you:

"For Quest developers: If you downloaded 1.39, delete the Oculus folder and all the Oculus integration assets. Redownload and reimport version 1.38 (you can find it online in the archives).

Once you import 1.38, go to Oculus > Tools > Create store compatible AndroidManifest.xml

Then go find the new AndroidManifest.xml in the Plugins > Android folder.

Then open it up and add the following line of code:   
Add the above line of code right before

Also change

to

Then build the app and it should work."

You can download the old version here:
https://developer.oculus.com/downloads/package/unity-integration-archive/

Comment: *Also change   <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO"/>

to    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>